# Character encoding, char to xml value

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to convert some characters (\t, \r, \n, "\r\n") to XML compatible "values". So '\t' should be `&#009;` and \r\n would be `&#xD;&#xA;`. I have tried using `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode()`, but without any success.

For those interested:

I wasn't able to get exactly the format I wanted, but the following seems to do the same:

`"\r\n".ToList().ForEach(c => Console.Write("&#x" + ((int)c).ToString("X") + ";"));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK entities like `\t`, `\r` or `\n` doesn't need to be "xml-escaped" (in fact you cannot escape them by default because it may be just source formatting or it may be real new line and you cannot know which one it is), so [best solution](http://forums.asp.net/t/1165023.aspx/1) I found was to convert those characters "by hand":

```
HttpUtility.HtmlEncode()
    .Replace("\n\r", "<br/>")
    .Replace("\n", "<br/>")  // Or use &#012; if you want it "binary safe"
    .Replace("\r", "<br/>")
    .Replace("\t", "&#009;");
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. Thing is that this is a project requirement that I must comply to. Is there no way to get from '\t' to '&#009;' except doing it manually?

Comment: @user1731444 none I know about... Maybe putting it into `CDATA` will preserve whitespaces?

Comment: Since no one else answered, and I think I found an alternate way, I will set your answer as the "Accepted" answer. Thanks for you time :)